# Issue committing files using GitHub app

Tags: git, version-control, github

I've been using the GitHub app for a while now, and recently it's given me some problems. My most recent problem has me up the wall. Here's what happened.

I noticed that some of my files were messed up on my GitHub page. The way the files were structured didn't make sense, and I needed to move my workspace anyway, so, I pulled down the repository. After I fixed some things, I went to my GitHub app, and created a new repository. I made it the same as my other repository, same name, description and file path. I clicked 'Create' and it made my repo. Now normally when clicking on the repo, it would give me a list of all my classes and files to be committed toward the project. However, that didn't happen in this case. Instead, GitHub gave me 2 files to be committed instead. .gitattributes and .gitignore. I was confused at first, so I just deleted the repo and started fresh. I cleaned out my Project making sure that there were no GitHub things left in the project itself, and recreated the Repo. This didn't work either, as the only files that were to be committed were .gitattributes and .gitignore. Flabbergasted, I tried again, this time moving my workspace with all my projects back to where it was cleaning my Project, and tried committing. Recreated the repo, same classpath, and it still didn't work.

Basically, what is happening is that the GitHub app is refusing to committ all of my files in my selected file (I have the correct file selected), and instead committing two files that are created by Git (.gitattributes & .gitignore). What is wrong with my GitHub, and how can I fix it? Please let me know if you need any additional details and I'll be happy to add them.

Comment: Is this Mac, Windows, Linux? what version of git? `git --version` Is this the offical github app? Could you expound on your statement "making sure there were no GitHub things left in the project", do you mean you deleted the .git hidden directory?

Comment: @spuder 1. Windows 2. Version: git version 1.8.1.msysgit.1 3. The official Github app, yes. 4. When you make a repository, there is a file that it places in the project named after that project. For instance, my GitHub project is called 'Sharks' so it would put a file called 'Sharks' in my project file that contains the .gitignore and .gitattributes documents. I always made sure to delete that.

Comment: The github app wont let me create a project that has the same name an another project. I'm guessing this git repo might be inside another git repo, or the git repo is corrupt. Try running a git clean -d. Other than that, I'm not sure.